# How to create a view that displays published version or latest revision

Tags: views

I need to create a REST Export view which can display 1 revision of each item of content of a particular content type. I need to be able to change which revision is displayed between the current published version and the latest version (whether that is a draft, published, etc). Ideally, choosing between published and latest would be done via the query string of the api call.

I've played around with the filters Latest Revision, Default Revision and more, but I can't figure out a solution.

Comment: Could you give some examples of what you have tried. If the issue is setting a GET variable request then this post might help https://mycode.blog/lakshmi/how-create-rest-api-using-views-drupal-8-and-drupal-9

Comment: I've found a solution that involves nesting Views, but I feel like there must be a better way of doing it.

My first Content View just selects NID and uses that as a contextual filter for the embedded view.

The 2nd Content Revisions View has all the data fields I need and limited to 1 item.

Both views have filters exposed for Default Revision and Published.

If the filters are null, I get most recent revision, if both =1 I get the current published version. However the JSON output is ugly with extra layers and arrays for single items.